# kivyMd with Multiple Screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to create a login and logout page using KivyMD and ScreenManager but it gives error continuously.

In the documentation of KivyMD it is only shown how you can create it with the App Class. However, my goal is to use the screen manager to manage two screens (login and logout), and functionality is when I click login, it should go to the logout page and show email and password on the 2nd screen and when I click logout, it should come back to the login screen. But it's throwing runtime `TypeError`

```
error:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "f:\PycharmProjects\kivyProject1\login_form.py", line 101, in <module>
     MOgggg().run()
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "f:\PycharmProjects\kivyProject1\login_form.py", line 90, in build
     kk=Builder.load_string(KV)
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 372, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 483, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 593, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 696, in parse_level
     _objects, _lines = self.parse_level(
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 696, in parse_level
     _objects, _lines = self.parse_level(
   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 756, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
# from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.config import Config

#set window size
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')


KV="""
ScreenManager:
    LoginScreen:
    LogoutScreen:


<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login"
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        padding: 180
        spacing: 10
        
        MDTextField:
            id: user_name
            hint_text:"Enter Username or Email"
            helper_text: "username must be unique"
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_left:"account"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            size_hint:(None,None)
            width:300
        
        MDTextField:
            id: password
            hint_text:"Password [8-20 words]"
            helper_text: "Password must contain number, spacial char"
            helper_text_mode:"on_focus"
            icon_left:"lock-off"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            size_hint:(None,None)
            width:300
            
        MDRaisedButton:
            text:"Login"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            on_release:
                app.submit()
                app.root.current="logout"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                
<LogoutScreen>:
    name:"logout"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDLabel:
                id: display_label
                text: ''
                theme_text_color: "Secondary"
                halign: 'center'
                font_style: "H6"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "LogOut"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            on_release:
                app.root.current="login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

"""
class LogoutScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MOgggg(MDApp):
    
    
    def build(self):
        kk=Builder.load_string(KV)
        return kk

    def submit(self):
        email=self.root.ids.user_name.text
        paasswod=self.root.ids.password.text
        
        self.root.ids.display_label.text=f"Hi {email} , You'r successfully Login!\n and this is your passwrd: {paasswod}"
        
        print(email,paasswod)

MOgggg().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is from bad formatting of your `kv` string. In the rule for `LogoutScreen`, the indentation after the `MDLabel:` is too much. The `kv` language is very sensitive to indentation. Just change:

```
    MDLabel:
            id: display_label
            text: ''
            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
            halign: 'center'
            font_style: "H6"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

to:

```
    MDLabel:
        id: display_label
        text: ''
        theme_text_color: "Secondary"
        halign: 'center'
        font_style: "H6"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
```